# Connecting to google using python stays blank

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am learning python and I am running into an issue

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

my firefox launches but it does not go on google.com like it is supposed to be but rather stays as a blank page.

Comment: What firefox and selenium versions are you using? Sounds like one of that incompatibility issues we often see reported.

Comment: I am using firefox 48.0 and I am not sure how to check the version of Selenium

Comment: I believe that your problem is the firefox start page.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069224/firefoxdriver-always-starting-on-firstrun-page-breaking-all-test-scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using chrome instead because your script does work.
so... http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/chromedriver_win32.zip Download that and extract it to your `python27/scripts` folder located in the root directory in the `C:\\` Drive and then run this script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.facebook.com')
```

And It should connect you to facebook.com  Hope I helped. :)