# Selenium - FirefoxDriver is opening Firefox+Windows10 welcome page instead of test URL

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

When I run the Selenium Webdriver (Java) script on Firefox, its opening the Firefox+Windows 10 welcome screen and hence my script is failing. I have seen the following similar posts

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937067/firefox-webdriver-opens-first-run-page-all-the-time)
and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069224/firefoxdriver-always-starting-on-firstrun-page-breaking-all-test-scripts)

and implemented all the things mentioned but its of no use.
PFB the code that I have tried:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore");
profile.setPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url", "about:blank");
profile.setPreference("startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional","about:blank");
profile.setPreference("browser.startup.homepage","about:blank");
profile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
profile.setPreference("toolkit.telemetry.reportingpolicy.firstRun", false);
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);        
driver.get(url);
```

Versions used
Firefox - 48.0.2 
Selenium - V3.0.0-beta3
Eclipse Mars
Java 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in URL.
This was my URL:

```
String url = "google.com/images";
```

I changed it to

```
String url = "http://google.com/images";
```

Now its working fine.