# When run selenium webdriver script it redirecting to first run page https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/44.0.2/firstrun/learnmore/

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run my selenium web driver script but it redirecting to first run page of firefox .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Q3X.png)

I am using firefox version 44.0.2.
How to disable it and run my script.

I have referred link [Firefox webdriver opens first run page all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937067/firefox-webdriver-opens-first-run-page-all-the-time) but didn't get the solution and also i have updated selenium web driver to version 2.52 but didn't work at all

Please help with your answer

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's happening because the new issue occurs with latest update of Mozilla firefox.

It's happening with me too.

To overcome from this issue you need to setPreference as `xpinstall.signatures.required", false` to firefox Profile and then pass it to driver object

```
firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
```

Below code is working fine for me.

```
static WebDriver driver=null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("xpinstall.signatures.required", false);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
    driver.get("https://www.google.de/");
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: welcome .. It feel good to hear the your issue is resolved ... :)