# how to use a FirefoxProfile with a IWebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium

I have lots of problem with Firefox. For most of them, I found lots of solution that use `FirefoxDriver` object. However I need to use `RemoteWebDriver`.

All the solutions to my problem use a `FirefoxProfile` object. is there a way to use this profile for the `IWebDriver`?

One of the thing I need to do is use the profile to do this:

[Firefox webdriver opens first run page all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937067/firefox-webdriver-opens-first-run-page-all-the-time)

here is how I use my `IWebDriver`:

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.Firefox(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the `FirefoxProfile` and then add it to the capabilities:

```
// create the profile
var profile = new FirefoxProfile();

// create the capabilities
var capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
capabilities.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, profile.ToBase64String());

// start the remote driver
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: thx I just found it too! However what would be the property to have it not ask for certificate? Where can I find a list of the preferences I can set in the profile?

Comment: type `about:config` in the address bar to get all the preferences.

Comment: and for the certificate, I would try `profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = True;`

Comment: thx a lot for your answer!! I'm gonna look in the configs. the certificates work, now all I have is that it tells me my connection is not secure (I use a proxy).